# Supporting /{_locale} in api platform routes

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I always need the locale when fetching data from API Platform, so I've setup the config

```yaml
api_platform:
    resource: .
    type: api_platform
    prefix: /{_locale}/api
    options:
      expose: true
```

This works when I call it in my code, Symfony $request object contains the locale as expected.

But when I run it from the /en/api docs page, the 'en' isn't getting passed.

```
No route found for \"GET https://mus.wip/%7B_locale%7D/api/instances/11\" (from \"https://mus.wip/en/api/docs\")
```

Not sure there's a way to solve this, besides *not* passing the locale in the route but rather as simply another property.  Any ideas on how to solve this?

[image]